# Redis-like SortedSet in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, sortedset, sorteddictionary, c5

Unlike the [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`SortedDictionary<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c(v=vs.110).aspx) from BCL,  The [`Sorted Sets`](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) from Redis is much more powerful.

- It allows access by `member`, quite like dictionary
- Sequence is determined on `score`, a different field from `member` and allows same value
- allows to get the min/max value with acceptable time-complexity

I don't want to combine `Dictionary` + `SortedSet` to achive my goal.

I am looking at [C5](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) library, not quite sure which class is the best for me.

**UPDATE**:
Finally I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274486/A-Better-Sorted-List-and-Dictionary), matching my requirement very well.

Comment: SortedSet<T> is probably as close as you will get. You may try and implement your own thing or use something third party. Take a look at this one: http://www.vcskicks.com/AVL-tree.php. Looks like a good start to me.

Comment: I don't think SortedSet<T> is suitable as it does not allow same `scrore`.

Comment: What makes you think the `SortedDictionary<T>` type wouldn't work for your purposes? It seems like it would handle all three of the cases you've mentioned pretty reasonably. I'm not sure how `Min` and `Max` are implemented on it, but it seems like you should be able to write something that does it correctly if that isn't natively supported.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, `SortedDictionary<T>` only allows to sort on a unique `key`; I need it to be sorted on another field(that is `score` in redis's sorted-set) and also allows dunplicate value.

Comment: ever find anything?

Comment: @KyleGobel, I wrote one by translating the C code from redis source code :)  it is a skip-list